# Transformar uma string JSON em um array não associativo em PHP

Tags: php, array, string, conversão

Boa tarde,

gostaria de converter uma string em um array não associativo em PHP, funções como json_encode/json_encode não estão funcionando corretamente.

String:

> palavra = '{"mundo":["CE","Supply"],"regional":["CSC","Regional
>   RJ/Verticalizadas"],"entidadeAgrupada":["G&G","BSA -
>   Gráfica"],"unidade":["GGI","BSA - Gráfica"],"area":null};

Estou tentando obter algo do tipo:

> [0=>["CE","Supply"],1=>["CSC","Regional
>   RJ/Verticalizadas"],2=>["G&G","BSA - Gráfica"],3=>["GGI","BSA -
>   Gráfica"]]

Agradeço desde já a atenção.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente isso:

`$resultado = array_values( json_decode( $palavra, true ) );`

O segundo parâmetro de [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-decode.php) define se ele retorna como objeto (false) ou array associativo (true). Uma vez com um array vc só precisa descartar as chaves usando [array_values()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-values.php);

Answer (score 0):

```
   <?php


    $data = '{ "mundo":["CE","Supply"], "regional":["CSC","Regional RJ/Verticalizadas"], "entidadeAgrupada":["G&G","BSA - Gráfica"], "unidade":["GGI","BSA - Gráfica"],"area":null }';


    $data1 = json_decode(trim($data), true);

    $data2 = $data1['mundo'];

    echo "<br>"; 
    print_r( $data1); 
    echo "<br>"; 
    echo "<br>";
     echo "<br>"; 
    print_r( $data2);
```

Resultado:

Array ( [mundo] => Array ( [0] => CE [1] => Supply ) [regional] => Array ( [0] => CSC [1] => Regional RJ/Verticalizadas ) [entidadeAgrupada] => Array ( [0] => G&G [1] => BSA - Gráfica ) [unidade] => Array ( [0] => GGI [1] => BSA - Gráfica ) [area] => )

Array ( [0] => CE [1] => Supply )