# Como transformar um vetor indexado por string em um vetor indexado por número?

Tags: php, array, índices

Como faço para transformar esse vetor $base:

```
$base = [
        [
            'name' => 'Rodrigo',
            'age' => '40'
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'Fabíola',
            'age' => '38'
        ]
    ];
```

Neste vetor $certo:

```
$certo = [
        ['Rodrigo','40'],
        ['Fabíola','38']
];
```

Valeu!

Comment: Talvez seja isso que você quer [`array_values()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-values.php)

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Remover índices do array](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/307529/remover-%c3%adndices-do-array)

Comment: Relacionada: [Transformar uma string JSON em um array não associativo em PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/159853/3774)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, eu creio que a implementação que você procura seja algo perto disto aqui:

1. Recebe o array base
2. Inicia a variável $certo, como array vazio.
3. Utiliza o [array_push](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-push.php) para incluir os valores dentro da variável $certo
4. Utiliza o [array_values](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-values.php) para isolar apenas os valores dos arrays.

Por fim o print_r com um

```
 serve apenas para melhor vizualiação. Espero ter ajudado.
```

`<?php
$base = [
    [
        'name' => 'Rodrigo',
        'age' => '40'
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'Fabíola',
        'age' => '38'
    ]
];

$certo = [];
foreach($base as $values) {
    array_push($certo, array_values($values));
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($certo);
echo "</pre>";`

Você pode acessar o [código em execução](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/322a34508bb63f5fd6a02527f83c8db51a176d7b)

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Interessante entendi. Obrigado por expor.

Answer (score 2):

Como dito e reiterado pelo [Icaro Martins](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/3774/icaro-martins) nesses três comentários:

- [Comentário 1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/540579/como-transformar-um-vetor-indexado-por-string-em-um-vetor-indexado-por-n%C3%BAmero/540593#comment971119_540579)
- [Comentário 2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/540579/como-transformar-um-vetor-indexado-por-string-em-um-vetor-indexado-por-n%C3%BAmero/540593#comment971121_540579)
- [Comentário 3](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/540579/como-transformar-um-vetor-indexado-por-string-em-um-vetor-indexado-por-n%C3%BAmero/540593#comment971123_540579)

Para obter um array com os valores de outro array use a função [`array_values()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-values.php). No seu caso específico use a função [`array_map`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-map.php) para aplicar a função `array_values()` ao elementos do array `$base`.

Caso seja mandatório obter a saída do array entre colchetes...

```
[['Rodrigo','40'], ['Fabíola','38']]
```

... é possível formatar a saída como um JSON com a função [`json_encode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-encode.php) usando a constante [`JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/json.constants.php) para tratar caractere Unicode de múltiplos bytes.

```
<?php
$base = [['name' => 'Rodrigo', 'age' => '40'],['name' => 'Fabíola', 'age' => '38']];

$certo = array_map('array_values', $base);         //Obtém um array contendo os valores de cada um dos elementos do array $base. 
echo json_encode($certo, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);  //Faz a impressão formatada do array $certo, caso a formatação não seja relevante faça apenas o print_r($certo).
//[["Rodrigo","40"],["Fabíola","38"]]

//print_r($certo)
/*Array(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Rodrigo
            [1] => 40
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Fabíola
            [1] => 38
        )

)*/
?>
```

<sup>Teste o exemplo no [IdeOne](https://ideone.com/BUluxM)</sup>